# Alternatives to Detrending data?

Tags: r, regression, time-series, multiple-regression, panel-data

How would you go about making an unbiased comparison of two interventions (old vs. New *prtcl.binary* (0 and 1; individual worksheets vs. group work).) when there's a negative longitudinal slope present (longitudinal meaning the data is measured over time, but not repeatedly since each student only had one measurement)?
[image]

The switch happened in 2014 (NOTE: there's little data for 2015, ~5 cases, so you can pretty much group it with 2014) But the mean comparison seems a little questionable when the previous intervention was having an effect already, see the negative slope before 2014.

So if my outcome is a count (i.e., number of days student did Y behavior), that is overdispersed (so I'm using a negative binomial dist.)

I was concerned with just comparing the one protocol to another using `prtcl.binary` as a dummy variable, so I added `year` to adjust the means for the the linear effect (black line) and an interaction between `year` and `prtcl.binary`, the differential, to compare the slopes. But I'm not sure this fixes my problem with interpreting the main effect of `prtcl.binary`.

```
MASS::glm.nb(formula = y.count ~ 1 + prtcl.binary + year + prtcl.binary : year, data = d0)
```

Someone told me this is a good case for detrending data (but I'm not fond of the idea of interpreting the regression coefficients of residuals; i.e., I'm dumb). Someone else suggested I used a mixed model and use year as a random effect.
I thought it might make sense to use the 2008 to 2013 data to predict a value for 2014 with a standard error and then compare it with the mean and standard error measured in just 2014.

Suggestions?

Comment: Sounds like you should use an interrupted time series.